# Difference between proving $\text{sup}_{t\geq 0} W_t=\infty$ and $\lim \text{sup}_{t\rightarrow \infty} W_t=\infty$ almost surely for Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

I have a proof for $\text{sup}_{t\geq 0} W_t=\infty$ and $\lim \text{sup}_{t\rightarrow \infty} W_t=\infty$ which in my eyes seem to be exactly the same.

> $\textit{Proof}: \text{sup}\;W_t=\infty$.$\;\;\;\;\;$ Let $A_n=\{\text{sup}_{t\geq 0} \{W_t\}\geq n\}$; this is monotonically non decreasing and therefore $\mathbb{P}(\text{sup}_{t\geq 0} \{W_t\}=\infty)=\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n).$ If $\tau_n$ is the first hitting time to the barrier $n$ then we have that $\mathbb{P}(A_n)=\mathbb{P}(\tau_n<\infty)$. Using the pdf of the first hitting time it is pretty easy to show that $\mathbb{P}(\tau_n<\infty)=1$ and then taking the limit of $n$ to $\infty$ gives us that $$\mathbb{P}(\text{sup}_{t\geq 0} \{W_t\}=\infty)=1$$ and the result follows.

Now the next proof:

> $\textit{Proof}:\lim \text{sup}_{t\rightarrow \infty} W_t=\infty.\;\;$ Let $\tau_n$ denote the first hitting time as before. As $\{\tau_{n+1}<\infty\}\subset\{\tau_n<\infty \}$ therefore $$\mathbb{P}(\lim \text{sup}_{t\rightarrow \infty} W_t=\infty)=\mathbb{P}\left (\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{\tau_n<\infty\}\right )=\mathbb{P}\left (\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\{\tau_n<\infty\}\right )$$ $$=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}\left (\tau_n<\infty\right )=1$$
>   And hence the result follows.

How are these proofs different? There does not seem to be any difference between the treatment of $\text{sup}$ and $\lim\text{sup}$. Intuitively I understand why they are equal for Brownian motion but cannot seem to understand the difference in these proofs. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ it holds that

$$\limsup_{t \to \infty} W_t(\omega)=\infty$$

iff

$$\sup_{t \geq 0} W_t(\omega)=\infty$$

(as the proofs in your question show, both statements hold with probability $1$). The reason why both statements are equivalent is that $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths:

> Let $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous mapping. Then $$\sup_{t \geq 0} f(t) = \infty$$ if and only if $$\limsup_{t \to \infty} f(t) = \infty.$$

This result follows easily from the fact that any continuous function is bounded on compact sets.

Note that this equivalence fails to hold for stochastic processes which do not have continuous sample paths (more precisely, for stochastic processes which can explode in finite time). For instance, if we define a (deterministic) process by

$$X_t := \begin{cases} \frac{1}{1-t}, & t \in (0,1), \\ 0, & t \geq 1 \end{cases}$$

then we have $\sup_{t \geq 0}X_t=\infty$, but $\limsup_{t \to \infty} X_t = 0$.